# How to write an AJAX URL for a backend hosted on the same server as the frontend?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

I'm doing a very small project that is hosted together (front and backend) on Heroku.

When I was working locally, I used `localhost:3000` for the frontend and `localhost:8000` for the backend, so the `url` property of my AJAX request would just point to `localhost:8000/login`, and my PHP backend would take it from there.

But now, I obviously can't use localhost when it's deployed, but I don't know where or how to point this URL. Here is an example of the code below:

```
// login jQuery call
$('.form_type_login').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let userEmail = $('#input-email').val();
  let userPassword = $('#input-password').val();

  document.querySelector('.form_type_login').reset();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userPassword: userPassword,
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    url: 'https://expensify-api-app.herokuapp.com/login',
  })
    .done(function (data) {
      if (data.authToken) {
        setCookie('authToken', data.authToken, 365);
        hideLoginModal();
        getTransactions(data.authToken);
      } else {
        if (data.jsonCode === 401 || data.jsonCode === 404) {
          alert('Incorrect email or password');
        }
        console.error(data.jsonCode, data.message);
      }
    })
    .fail(function () {
      alert('Connection failed. Please try again later');
      console.error('$.post failed');
    });
});
```

If I were to write `localhost` in the URL, this function would fetch `index.php`, which looks like this:

```
<?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');

$request = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');

$authToken = $_GET['authToken'];

switch ($request) {
  case '/login' :
    require __DIR__ . '/login.php';
    $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];
    $userPassword = $_POST['userPassword'];
    echo login($userEmail, $userPassword);
    break;
  case '/transactions' :
    require __DIR__ . '/transactions.php';
    echo getTransactions($authToken);
    break;
  case '/create-transaction' :
    require __DIR__ . '/create-transaction.php';
    $authToken = $_POST['authToken'];
    $transactionDate = $_POST['transactionDate'];
    $transactionMerchant = $_POST['transactionMerchant'];
    $transactionAmount = $_POST['transactionAmount'];
    echo createTransaction($authToken, $transactionDate, $transactionMerchant, $transactionAmount);
    break;
}


?>
```

So the URL is held in `$request`, and then a switch statement decides which function to use, and then returns the data.

But even if I point the URL to `index.php`, it looks like `url: '../../backend/index.php/login',`, which is obviously not right.

What can I do here?

For clarity, I left a pic of my file structure. I have never built a frontend and backend on the same server, so I really don't know which way to start, and I can't be clear enough to Google the question properly.

Thanks in advance everyone.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to call just url: `/login`?

Comment: I've tried, it just makes the request URL "https://expensify-api-app.herokuapp.com/login", which returns a 404

Comment: i would send it to "index.php", but the index uses "$request = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');" 
to grab the url for the switch statement, so i need to include "/login" for the index.php to do the switch statement properly

Comment: Create a folder called login and then create a file index.php in there so `login/index.php` or else make the request as /login.php directly. I suggest you to use URL directing using redirects in `.htaccess` [here](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)